# How to Enable "Micro Focus UFT Agent" Add-on in Internet Explorer (IE) browser using command line

Tags: internet-explorer, command-line, microfocus, leanft

I want to enable "Micro Focus UFT Agent" Add-on in Internet Explorer (IE) browser using command line.

This is how we use to do manually:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think it is impossible to achieve such a feature through a command line. What you can try is to modify the corresponding value in the registry through a script under this path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings\{[addon key]} `